# How is ECR (Electron Counting Rule) done in a structure?

Tags: crystal-structure, materials, surface-chemistry, nanotechnology

I've been told how to apply the ECR to GaAs{001}(2×4) in my lectures but it makes no sense to me and I don't seem to be able to find any other sources that explain this. (This is a further question on another one posted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605758/which-is-the-correct-gaas0012%c3%974-structure/605763?noredirect=1#comment1363719_605763) .)

**Could anyone please tell me how this is done? Or give me some sources on how to apply the ECR?**

*"This question has been previously asked on the [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/607476/edit) where it is bountied, but I was told that I should try and post it here as I might be more successful in getting an answer."*

---

This is the explanation I have been given for the following structure:

[image]

Count the number of electrons, going down to two of As atoms level with the bottom of the trench and count per unit mesh. There are 8+4 As atoms = 60 valence electrons. There are 6 Ga atoms = 18 electrons. Hence a total of 78 electrons.

*Count the bonds that need to be filled :*

*1. 3 As dimer bonds = 6 e*

*2. 6 As dangling bonds (2 per dimer) = 12 e*

*3. Ga dangling bonds (sideways into trench) are empty = 0 e*

*4. 8 backbonds from top As dimers = 16 e*

*5. 12 backbonds from Ga to 3rd row As = 24 e*

*6. 16 backbonds (bulk-like) from 3rd row As to underlying Ga: each takes 5/4 e from As giving 5×16/4 = 20 e*

*78 electrons for both totals so structure is neutral and should be stable.*

I am trying to learn how to do this as I am trying to prove that this is not applicable to the GaAS{001}(2x1) structure, which I believe to be represented like the image below from the help I was given at a previous related question, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605758/which-is-the-correct-gaas0012%c3%974-structure).

[image]

Comment: You do know that cross-posting is frowned upon? BTW that bounty on Physics is probably serious waste of rep.

Comment: I was informed to do so, I didn't know that it was frowned upon, my apologies. I shall take the question. And it does not seem a waste of rep for me as I do not know how to do this and would love to learn.

Comment: Mithoron, if you could help me that would be very appreciated. Thank you for telling me about the rules.

Comment: Umm, [GaAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium_arsenide) is simply tetragonal and I don't see a reason for some electron counting.